# How do I check for OPTIONS request in django-rest-framework 3.0 serializer?

Tags: rest, http, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a serializer with dynamic fields in DRF 3.0, as explained [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields). I am supposed to return different fields for POST, GET and OPTIONS requests.

However, it seems that when I make an OPTIONS request to the server, my serializer gets called with 'POST' in `request.method`. 
I have also looked into `request._method`, but it's the same thing. So, how do I differentiate between 'POST and 'OPTIONS' ?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you make the request? With jQuery Ajax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. First not getting why, with my custom permission classes enabled, I did not receive any info on ACTIONS in the metadata. AdelaN pointed me in the right direction here.

As a solution I added an additional 'if' to my permission class which checks the request._request.method to be OPTIONS like so:

```
    if request.method == 'POST' or request.method == 'DELETE':
        # Make an exception for redirected OPTIONS requests
        # See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30460409/how-do-i-check-for-options-request-in-django-rest-framework-3-0-serializer
        if request._request.method == "OPTIONS":
            return True
```

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery Ajax, you may try to add the following option in the Ajax options:

```
headers: {'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'OPTIONS'}
```

I have to do to same for sending PATCH request.

Comment: Actually, the method OPTIONS is correctly invoked, but DRF makes another POST request under the hood in order to obtain all informations about the request info. So the serializer sees it as a POST request, no matter what. I will just have to find another way to solve this.